# How to get Spring to autowire integration test class using multiple contexts?

Tags: java, spring, junit

One of my integration tests uses multiple Spring context files. It seems that Spring only autowires in beans from the first context and not the second. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to work around the problem?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml"})
@Configurable
public class UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    UserDataOnDemand dod;
    // @Autowired does not work for this bean from applicationContext-security.xml
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dod.init();
        // workaround for autowiring problem
        userDetailsService = (UserDetailsService)ctx.getBean("userDetailsService");
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadUser() {
        UserDetails ud = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("david@somewhere.co.za");
        Assert.assertEquals("david@somewhere.co.za", ud.getUsername());
    }
}
```

I am using Spring 3.0.3.

Here is the stack trace when I uncomment the @Autowired line for UserDetailsService:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'za.co.acme.app.security.UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService za.co.acme.app.security.UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.configureBean(AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj:89)
    at za.co.acme.app.security.UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest.(UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:202)
```

The bean is definitely there since the "by name" lookup works, and it is of the correct type.

Answer (score 7):

A workaround is to create a new single configuration file (let's call it "test-configuration.xml") which is including the both applicationContext.xml and applicationContext-security.xml. Then you can use these configurations within your tests.

test-configuration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml"/>
</beans>
```

UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test-configuration.xml")
@Configurable
public class UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar setup and it's working fine for me.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-struts.xml", "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseTests {
```

My guess is that the problem is in the setup of your project. Do you use Eclipse? Does it load the context files from the /bin folder or from a /src folder? Did you exclude "applicationContext-security.xml" from the build?

Comment: Well the fact that manual lookup of the UserDetailsService bean works indicates that that context files are in fact being loaded ok. Its just the autowiring part that isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, the solution fixed my problem is switch the bean expose through Interface. (i.e) Your reference Bean Type should be a **Interface** instead of its implementation class

In your case change the concrete Class `UserDetailsService` reference with its interface.

**For Example:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml"})
@Configurable
public class UserDetailsServiceImplIntegrationTest {

  //modified code  
  @Autowired
  IUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    //your test cases follows

}
```

**NOTE:** I know this wont be a sensible solution, But just give a try, I worried lot because of this same error and finally changed my reference and it worked fine. Hope it would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Spring to act on those annotations. In the relevant context file you should add the following:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Now it'll scan for those annotations. See the Spring documentation on [Annotation-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

To limit the number of classes it needs to scan so you don't needlessly scan packages with no autowiring, add this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

See the docs for [Auto-detecting components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection) for more on that, as well as the XML namespaces you'll need to add to reference those tags.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the bean for `userDetailsService` in your xml? You might need to add a `@Qualifier` annotation with the bean name, and then putting a `<qualifier>` tag in the context.

Take a look at [Spring's documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) on the topic.

Comment: I did try that and also tried using @Resource without any luck. I only have one UserDetailsService bean so by type should also work. The error messages indicates that no bean with the correct type could be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems.It seems that there is a proxy UserDataOnDemand instead of the real UserDataOnDemand .