# How to disable Spring autowiring for a certain bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are some class in jar (external library), that uses Spring internally.
So library class has structure like a:

```java
@Component
public class TestBean {

    @Autowired
    private TestDependency dependency;

    ...
}
```

And library provides API for constructing objects:

```java
public class Library {

    public static TestBean createBean() {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(springConfigs);
        return context.getBean(TestBean);
    }
}
```

In my application, I have config:

```java
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestBean bean() {
        return Library.createBean();
    }
}
```

It's throw en exception: `Field dependency in TestBean required a bean of type TestDependency that could not be found.`.

But Spring should not trying to inject something, because bean is already configured.

Can i disable Spring autowiring for a certain bean?

Comment: How do you know bean is already configured?

Comment: Since `Library.createBean()` is creating your object, why have you put @Autowired above `TestDependency`

Comment: It's not me. It's a library source code.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing, because `Library.createBean` use Spring internally.

Comment: Might it be that TestDependency is not found in the component-scan classpath?

Comment: IMO - problem is spring context created by TestConfig and Library, both are different. Also if you wanna load third party components into your system, best way is to configure it xml files instead of loading using component-scan.

Comment: @asg, exactly!!

Comment: Yep... a simple configuration seems to be still discussed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13043

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on @Juan's answer, created a helper to wrap a bean not to be autowired:

```
public static <T> FactoryBean<T> preventAutowire(T bean) {
    return new FactoryBean<T>() {
        public T getObject() throws Exception {
            return bean;
        }

        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return bean.getClass();
        }

        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}

...

@Bean
static FactoryBean<MyBean> myBean() {
    return preventAutowire(new MyBean());
}
```

Comment: The trick works. But note that the bean won't be wrapped by a proxy, i.e. to enable effect of `@Validated` or `@Transactional`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;  
...  
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<TestBean> bean() {
        TestBean bean = Library.createBean();

        return new FactoryBean<TestBean>()
        {
            @Override
            public TestBean getObject() throws Exception
            {
                return bean;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getObjectType()
            {
                return TestBean.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSingleton()
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly but you can add required=false `(@Autowired(required=false))` in your autowired annotation. But be careful that might get you NullPointer exception

Comment: I can't. `TestBean` it's a class from a library source code.

Comment: I am afraid for that you have to go by XML approach in that create beand for TestDependency and mark it autowire-candidate=false then it won't consider that for autowiring

Comment: If I mark @Autowired(require = false) then will it always be null or will it try to  autowire it and if it fails just continue?

Comment: @jDub9:check asg's comment `IMO - problem is spring context created by TestConfig and Library, both are different. Also if you wanna load third party components into your system, best way is to configure it xml files instead of loading using component-scan.` u need to import in ur scan package xml file of ur library

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's impossible to disable autowiring for a specific bean.

So there is some workaround.
We can make wrapper for a target bean and use it instead of original bean:

```java
public class TestBeanWrapper {

    private final TestBean bean;

    public TestBeanWrapper(TestBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    public TestBean bean() {
        return bean;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public TestBeanWrapper bean() {
        return new TestBeanWrapper(Library.createBean());
    }
}

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestBeanWrapper bean;

    ...
}
```