# Spring bean without any id and name

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Can you help me, please?
I want to create Spring bean using **annotation** without any name or id.
Like in xml config

```
<bean class="com.my.class.Nane"/>
```

I just need to disable Autowiring bean by name or id, only by class name!

Comment: By default it will take class name (with lowercase first letter) as id or method name (if it's created with method). In your case "nane" will be id.

Comment: @aleshka-batman,  I know it, but I want don't have any id or name, I know how to do it by xml config

Comment: I mean even this <bean class="com.my.class.Nane"/> will have id "nane".

Comment: @aleshka-batman, are you sure, because when I use XML Spring cant Autowire by name?

Comment: I confirm the @aleshka-batman comment. the default id is the name of the class. It doesn't make sens to create a bean without any id.

Comment: @aleshka-batman is right, from the docs [1.3.1. Naming beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanname): "You are not required to supply a name or id for a bean. If no name or id is supplied explicitly, the container generates a unique name for that bean."

Comment: @Tobías, a name will as a full class name, I have already checked it, thanks. Maybe You know how disable injection be the name, and allow only by class name?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think it possible out of the box. Maybe it can be achieved with a custom ApplicationContext / BeanFactory implementation. But I can't imagine how to do it without breaking anything. I think name injection is part of the core of spring.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880210/how-to-disable-spring-autowiring-for-a-certain-bean