# Spring injects @Autowired fields during manual class instantiation

Tags: java, spring

In my project I am surprised to see that Spring (4.3) seems to attempt to autowire dependencies for classes even when they are manually instantiated.

`MyClass.java` (note Lombok annotations):

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyClassDependency dependency;
}
```

`MyClassDependency.java` uses a factory method and no Spring annotations:

```
public class MyClassDependency {
    public static MyClassDependency create() { return new MyClassDependency(); }
}
```

Spring config resulting in `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
        return new MyClass(MyClassDependency.create());
    }
}
```

Providing the bean makes Spring happy:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
        return new MyClass(); // let autowire inject dependencies
    }
    @Bean
    public MyClassDependency myClassDependency() {
        return MyClassDependency.create();
    }
}
```

This was a big surprise to me. I'd like to have the simpler first version of the config... Where is this behavior coming from / controlled? (It's possible that I missed it or pulled it from some dependencies).

PS: To clarify, `MyClass` code is outside of my control but I can change Spring config. I am looking to understand how Spring intercepts the constructor call withing a bean method and whether constructor can be used instead.

Comment: Remove `@Autowired` from the field if you don't need it. The fact that you use constructor injection should be enough. So remove the default constructor, leave only the one taking the dependency and remove `@Autowired` from your class.

Comment: by removing `@Autowired` on `private MyClassDependency dependency;` should work

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified - MyClass is the class outside of my control. I only control Spring config.

Comment: can you differentiate these two use cases? @alexandroid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following:

1. You annotated a field with @Autowired - that tells Spring, that there is a dependency that needs to be injected there
2. You annotated a method with @Bean - which puts the return value into Spring's context.
3. When Spring processes the return value of the @Bean-annotated object, it starts to proces its annotations - and there is a field with an annotation, that tells Spring to inject a dependency there, even if the field already has a value assigned.
4. Spring tries to inject the dependency here, but that dependency does not exist in the Spring context, so injection fails.

So having @Bean, but manually injecting an @Autowired dependency conflicts each other, you may now understand, why - you shall not inject Autowired beans manually! Autowired is an annotation that tells he CI container to do some injection work.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the fact that Spring builds the dependency tree from the leaves up, so on #3 it will look for the dependency to auto-wire and ignore the method implementation I provided for it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a hacky way of doing that, as described in this [old Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880210/how-to-disable-spring-autowiring-for-a-certain-bean).

```
public static <T> FactoryBean<T> preventAutowire(T bean) {
    return new FactoryBean<T>() {
        public T getObject() throws Exception {
            return bean;
        }

        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return bean.getClass();
        }

        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}

...

@Bean
static FactoryBean<MyBean> myBean() {
    return preventAutowire(new MyBean());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wasn't really looking for the work around, I was trying to understand why Spring ignores my method implementation and looks for the dependency... I missed the fact that it builds them from the leaves of the tree up.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify further a bit on what answers like Celebi pointed out.

Your surprise at how it behaves seems to stem from looking at a portion of the wiring behavior backwards, versus how it works.

You wrote:

> ..I am surprised to see that Spring (4.3) seems to attempt to autowire
>   dependencies for classes even when they are manually instantiated.

It is not trying to wire the non-bean "MyClassDependency" class without it having a @Bean notation. In fact from the Spring perspective it does not "see" that class at all.

The other side of the code is Asking for a bean of class name "MyClassDependency" - That is what is initiating the attempt to go find "MyClassDependency" and create a wiring. Of course, it does not find any matching bean of that name/criteria.

Your question seems more regarding the need to understand why it is behaving in the manner you observed and I believe this is why.

Functionally, you likely already solved your own problem. By adding @Bean on top of MyClassDependency, for Spring you now have a visible bean available for use by the other code requesting it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was thrown off by the fact that Spring went to build the dependency tree and instantiate dependency, ignoring the implementation of the @Bean method I provided...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AbstractFactoryBean` as in this example

```java
package com.stackoverflow.q53737175;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    /** The Constant SPRING_CLASS_RULE. */
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    /** The spring method rule. */
    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(this.myClass);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class SpringConfig {

        @Bean
        public FactoryBean<MyClass> myClass() {

            return new AbstractFactoryBean<MyClass>() {

                @Override
                public Class<?> getObjectType() {

                    return MyClass.class;
                }

                @Override
                protected MyClass createInstance() throws Exception {

                    return new MyClass(MyClassDependency.create());
                }

            };
        }
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class MyClass {

        @Autowired
        private MyClassDependency dependency;
    }

    static class MyClassDependency {
        public static MyClassDependency create() {
            return new MyClassDependency();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but a workaround is not what I was looking for. I was looking to understand the Spring behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is coming from the `@Bean` annotation [definition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts):

> 1.12.1. Basic Concepts: @Bean and @Configuration
>
> The central artifacts in Spring’s new Java-configuration support are @Configuration-annotated classes and @Bean-annotated methods.
>
> The @Bean annotation is used to indicate that a method instantiates, configures, and initializes a new object **to be managed by the Spring IoC container**. For those familiar with Spring’s `<beans/>` XML configuration, the @Bean annotation plays the same role as the `<bean/>` element. You can use @Bean-annotated methods with any Spring @Component. However, they are most often used with @Configuration beans.

`preventAutowire` [proposed by Fabio Manzano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838890/1091731) is an acceptable workaround until [another solution is provided by Spring](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8396).

Comment: See, that's the part which was confusing to me - I thought that by annotating a method with `@Bean` I will tell Spring to call that method in order to instantiate that object and ignore the `@Autowired` parts of it. It looks like Spring did not run that method but saw `@Autowired` and kept building the dependency tree down, then looking for definitions of dependencies bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will override the instance of `MyClassDependency` you provided. Because you are defining `MyClass` as a bean with the autowired dependency. You are telling Spring to manage it and Spring is doing what you are asking for.

You can definitely use constructor injection by annotating the constructor with `@Autowired`, but if you don't have access to the source code of `MyClass`, it is out of the question.

This is the simplest configuration you can get without changing the source code of `MyClass` or fiddling with Spring bean lifecycle.

If you want to understand the bean lifecycle, you can refer to the [IoC Container documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's the part which was confusing to me - I thought that by annotating a method with `@Bean` I will tell Spring to call that method in order to instantiate that object and ignore the `@Autowired` inside of it. It looks like Spring did not run that method but saw `@Autowired` and kept building the dependency tree down, then looking for definitions of dependencies bottom up.