# How to set an Autowired field in an Aspect from junit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-aop

I have a Aspect that has an Autowired field config and in my unit test I would like to set a mock to config after defining mock behavior.

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration config;

...
```

Unit Test:

```
@Autowired
private Configuration config;

@Before
public void setup() {
    when(config.getInt(TTL)).thenReturn(10000);
    // set confing to Aspect
}
```

I know spring has `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` for setting an autowired field, but I don't have a reference to the aspect object.

Comment: How did you define your mocks? Also, it looks like you're using mockito and you may have a chance for an easy way with [Springokito](https://bitbucket.org/hadadil/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations) but I have not had the chance of testing it with aspects so far...

Comment: I am using Mockito

Comment: I was also interested to know how you defined your mocks. Also, did you get the chance to look at Springokito?

Comment: It is a bean in a configuration. I have not looked an Springokito yet.

Comment: If it's a bean in a _test context_ then it should automatically pick it up. Alternatively with Springockito you should be able to replace an actual bean definition with an _inline-mock_ via the [@ReplaceWithMock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354473/springockito-how-to) annotation if i remember correctly, without the need of additional contexts & all that stuff