# Spring Autowiring a list into a bean results in a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, autowired

In a Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE project I want to create and autowire a list that contains some enum to some service.

Unfortunately the autowiring fails (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException), while I can retrieve the bean in the context and manually wire the dependency.

Here is a small testcase showcasing the issue (using Spring 3.1.3 and JUnit):

**The XML context (int package /junk):**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="junk"/>

    <util:list id="myList" value-type="junk.GreatThings">
        <value>SUPER</value>
        <value>COOL</value>
    </util:list>

</beans>
```

**The enum:**

```
package junk;
public enum GreatThings {AMAZING, GREAT, SUPER, COOL}
```

**The test class (in package junk - I've removed the import for clarity):**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:junkcontext.xml"})  
public class TestAutowiringSupport {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("myList") List<GreatThings> greatThings;

    @Test public void testSuperCool() {
        Assert.assertThat(greatThings, hasItem(SUPER));
        Assert.assertThat(greatThings, hasItem(COOL));
    }
}
```

This result in a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.
I have try to put a @Qualifier with my bean id to help Spring to perform the wiring without any success.

My IDE is however able to detect the wiring by itself:
[image]

And if I use the Spring lifecycle callbacks to get back the bean and wire it manually then, it is fine.

**Version that compiles and runs fine:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:junkcontext.xml"})
public class TestAutowiringSupport implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    ApplicationContext ctx;
    List<GreatThings> greatThings;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {this.ctx = ctx;}

    @PostConstruct
    public void manualWiring() {greatThings = (List<GreatThings>) ctx.getBean("myList");}

    @Test public void testSuperCool() {
        Assert.assertThat(greatThings, hasItem(SUPER));
        Assert.assertThat(greatThings, hasItem(COOL));
    }

}
```

What's wrong with the autowiring in this case ?

Comment: Try adding `@Qualifier("myList")` to `greatThings` in `TestAutowiringSupport`

Comment: I've tried that, but it does the same thing... NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Comment: Try adding @Component to the `TestAutowiringSupport` class

Comment: try <context:annotation-config/> http://stackoverflow.com/a/4217948/410677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some problem with generics.

With Spring 4.1 I am able to execute this code: where `greatThings` is of type `List<Object>`

```
@Qualifier("myList")
@Autowired List<Object> greatThings;

@Test
public void testSuperCool() {
    Assert.assertThat(greatThings, Matchers.hasSize(2));
    Assert.assertThat(greatThings, Matchers.hasItem(GreatThings.SUPER));
    Assert.assertThat(greatThings, Matchers.hasItem(GreatThings.COOL));        
}
```

Comment: The weird thing was that Intellij was able to detect the wiring and to provide auto-completion in the list declaration. That gave me the feeling that the setting was "correct" but maybe bugged or badly supported in Spring 3.1. Thank you for this confirmation.

Comment: Is the same code able to execute with a List<GreatThings> ???
I can't run the code in Spring 3 even with a List<Object>

Comment: @Guillaume: `List<GreatThings>` does not work, only `List<Object>` - I tryed to make this in my answer explicit in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation), placing the `@Autowired` annotation over a typed collection means "find all beans of the given type (`GreatThings` in your case), put them in a collection and inject that collection". You are getting the exception because there are no beans of type `GreatThings` declared.

The problem is that there is no easy way to declare enum values as beans. Then again I don't see the use case to be honest.